# Getting FileSystemException stating Invalid argument while calling setOwner in Java

Tags: java, java-8

I am changing the ownership of a file via the code which looks like below:-

```
private static void setOwner(String filePath, String owner, int currentCount, int retryCount)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    try {
        Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
        UserPrincipalLookupService lookupService = FileSystems.getDefault().getUserPrincipalLookupService();
        UserPrincipal userPrincipal;
        userPrincipal = lookupService.lookupPrincipalByName(owner);
        Files.setOwner(path, userPrincipal);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (currentCount >= retryCount) {
        throw e;
        } else {
        LOG.info("Retrying setting owner to {}, owner: {}, currentCount: {}, retryCount: {}", filePath, owner,
            currentCount, retryCount);
        Thread.sleep(Long.parseLong(ConfigManager.getOwnerRetryInterval()));
        setOwner(filePath, owner, currentCount + 1, retryCount);
        }
    }
    }
```

But some time the above code is throwing an exception which looks like below:-

```
servicemix.log:java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /data/www/htdocs/media.live/product/98/68091/5.jpg: Invalid argument
servicemix.log- at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)[:1.8.0_74]
servicemix.log- at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)[:1.8.0_74]
servicemix.log- at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)[:1.8.0_74]
servicemix.log- at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Posix.setOwners(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:252)[:1.8.0_74]
servicemix.log- at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Posix.setOwner(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:274)[:1.8.0_74]
servicemix.log- at sun.nio.fs.FileOwnerAttributeViewImpl.setOwner(FileOwnerAttributeViewImpl.java:100)[:1.8.0_74]
servicemix.log- at java.nio.file.Files.setOwner(Files.java:2127)[:1.8.0_74]
servicemix.log- at com.jab.orchestratorservice.basecomponent.utils.Misc.setOwner(Misc.java:161)[11:basecomponent:0.0.1]
servicemix.log- at com.jab.orchestratorservice.basecomponent.utils.Misc.setOwner(Misc.java:169)[11:basecomponent:0.0.1]
servicemix.log- at com.jab.orchestratorservice.basecomponent.utils.Misc.setOwner(Misc.java:169)[11:basecomponent:0.0.1]
```

This exception is intermittent and does not come always even for the same file. Also the exception message `Invalid argument` seems to be very generic.

Can someone let me know what could be the problem & when does this error `Invalid Argument` can come?

Environment:-

- Java 8
- Apache Servicemix 7.0.0.M2
- Debian 8

Comment: Instead of `FileSystems.getDefault()`, can you try with `path.getFileSystem().provider()`? You could be trying to change the owner of a file in a different filesystem than the one the JVM runs it.

Comment: `trying to change the owner of a file in a different filesystem than the one the JVM runs it.` - Can you explain it a bit more? The file and JVM are on the same machine (Debian 8).

Comment: As a side note, don’t use recursion for implementing retry. There are loops for that purpose.

Comment: They could be on the same machine but located on separate file systems. See the output of `df -h`, that will list all your filesystems.

Comment: @Tunaki: if the Java `FileSystem` is different, a `ProviderMismatchException` will be thrown. From the stack trace we can conclude that this test has been passed and below that, the user is just an `int` id. See [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/nio/fs/UnixFileAttributeViews.java#264)